On Form submit; convert the input value into a hyperlink by combining domain and user input (slug), with input value as display name
Thanks for reading. I'm a novice with simple needs, looking to automate actions and make workflows more efficient, but I'm finding all the related posts and documentation difficult. I'm looking for help please as I am now just going around in circles, and can no longer remember the script which got me the closest result. School boy error...
I have a Google Form where users are required to upload images and then input What3Words locations as the answer to a couple of different questions.
I've already setup an OnFromSubmit script in the Google Sheets form responses spreadsheet to convert the multiple Google Drive URL locations in a single cell for the images into hyperlinks, but I would also like to convert the input W3W locations into hyperlinks that can then be clicked on.
I have a script that combines the domain and the user input (slug), but the URL is longer than I would like displayed on the spreadsheet, so I'm looking to take the user input e.g. "daring.lion.race", convert it to the hyperlink "https://what3words.com/daring.lion.race", BUT retain the original input as the display text  "daring.lion.race".
I have tried variations of the below, using RichTextValueBuilder, but I'm struggling. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
function onEdit(e) {
W3WURL1(e);
W3WURL2(e);
}

function W3WURL1(e) {
var range = e.range;
var responseArray = e.values;
var W3Wprefix = "https://what3words.com/";

    responseArray[4] = W3Wprefix + e.values[4]; 
    range.setValues([responseArray]);
}

function W3WURL2(e) {
var range = e.range;
var responseArray = e.values;
var W3Wprefix = "https://what3words.com/";

    responseArray[7] = W3Wprefix + e.values[7]; 
    range.setValues([responseArray]);
}

I feel I am on the right lines with the below, but I'm stuck.
function onEdit(e) {
 var cell = e.range.getCell(1,5);
 var text = cell.getValue();
 const domain = "https://what3words.com/";
 var url = domain + (text);
 var richTextValueBuilder= SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
 richTextValueBuilder.setText(text);
  {
   richTextValueBuilder.setLinkUrl(url)
 }
 cell.setRichTextValue(richTextValueBuilder.build());
}

Answers for Tanaike
The OnFormSubmit trigger is related to a different script running on the same spreadsheet. Due to my limited knowledge of writing scripts, I have separated the scripts into different files, although I imagine they could be combined somehow into one Script.
The onEdit and W3W functions are my attempt to run a new process on the same spreadsheet without affecting the Script that works. I have used onEdit as this is what the online examples I found and used as a basis for writing these scripts used — perhaps I should be using OnFormSubmit too? However, as it worked for my original W3W script referenced above, I have continued to use it.
Again, due of my lack of knowledge, because I need the script to convert values in 2 columns, I created W3W1 and W3W2 to target the different columns.
An example of my desired output:
Form Input Value
Col E — daring.lion.race
Col H — pretty.needed.chill
Cell value after Script has run
Col E — daring.lion.race
Col H — pretty.needed.chill
Apologies if I've misunderstood, but I hope that answers your questions and better explains what I'm looking to do.

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the relationship between the OnFromSubmit trigger, 2 onEdit function, and the functions W3WURL1 and W3WURL2? And, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Thanks for your comment Tanaike, any help would be appreciated.

There is a character limit and I'm now unable to edit my original comment which I pressed send too early on, so I will try and add my answer to your questions to the bottom of the original post.

Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your updated question, I couldn't still understand the relationship between the OnFromSubmit trigger, 2 onEdit function, and the functions W3WURL1 and W3WURL2. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

My understanding of the relationship, in the way that it is currently setup, is that the on form submit is part of a script that's not shown here, but runs on the same spreadsheet when a from is submitted. Then, the onEdit script runs to perform the W3W1 and W3W2 functions. I am looking to replace the W3W function with a better script which allows the original input to be shown as the hyperlink display name.

Using the onFormSubmit function, listing multiple functions to run in order, the below script did what I wanted.
function onFormSubmit(e) {
    W3WURL1(e);
}

function W3WURL1(e) {
    var cell = e.range.getCell(1,5); //where column 5 contains the URL text value I want to retain
    var text = cell.getValue();
    const domain = "https://what3words.com/"; //the domain I want to use as a prefix to the input value in column 5 to create the URL
    var url = domain + text; //combining the domain and input value to create the URL
    var richTextValueBuilder= SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
        .setText(text)
        .setLinkUrl(url);
    cell.setRichTextValue(richTextValueBuilder.build());
}

